# Android ListView with drawable int array for performance boost

Tags: android, performance, list, listview, drawable

I have a lot of drawables that I pass into int arrays and then load them inside my constructors. The approach looks like this:

```
public static final int contactsArray[] = { R.drawable.contact_image_1,
R.drawable.contact_image_2, 
R.drawable.contact_image_3,
R.drawable.contact_image_4,
R.drawable.contact_image_5 };
```

After that, with current approapch:

```
public static List<DataModel> getContacts()
{
List<DataModel> items = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
items.add(new DataModel(contactsArray[0]));
items.add(new DataModel[1]));
items.add(new DataModel(contactsArray[2]));
items.add(new DataModel(contactsArray[3]));
items.add(new DataModel(contactsArray[4]);
return items;
}
```

With the old approach:

```
public static List<DataModel> getContacts() {
List<DataModel> items = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
items.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.contact_image_1));
items.add(new DataModel.drawable.contact_image_2));
items.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.contact_image_3));
items.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.contact_image_4));
items.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.contact_image_5);
return items;
}
```

I use the ViewHolder Pattern for my lists, and pass the `getContacts()` method as the adapter argument.

My question is if it does make a performance difference if I first load the drawables inside an int array or instead just pass each drawable Resource reference inside each constructor parameter.
Thx.

Comment: You are the right person to find out because you have all the code already. What is your impression?

Comment: well I guess, it should be the same performance because in the end I am already accesing them directly statically through the R class.

Comment: And now I feel stupid fro not noticing that. Thx for making me ask myself.

Answer (score 1):

This change just like keeping files paths in an array and this will not affect performance because image's loading occur in adapter

Comment: I see, despite the fact I knew that I actually don't create objects but instead only reference resource paths I was thinking in terms of object creation. Thx for your input.